# Почему слайдер не работает в Opera?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Доброго времени друзья. Учусь делать слайдер вот ссылочка http://jsbin.com/xitah/4/edit.
Такой вопрос: Почему в опере вообще не работает? А в IE  transition: background-size ease 7s;  не пашет?

Comment: ссылка не рабочая

Comment: Уже рабочая